# Qt How to find out from where the closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) fired

Tags: c++, qt

I have in my main window 2 triggers 
1. from the menu that closed totaly the app
2. from he window X button that ignored and just hide the window.
I'm using this SIGNAL/SLOTS
how can I know from where is it being triggered?.

In the `closeEvent`:

```
connect(ui->actionQuit, SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(CloseWin()));

void MainWindow::CloseWin()
{

   close();

}
// triggered from the ui->actionQuit amd from the X button

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{

    // how can i know from where its bean triggered?     
    hide();
        event->ignore();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions are possible:

1. connect menu item (`QAction`) signal to a separate slot and call `qApp->quit()` there
2. use `sender()` method inside your slot to determine the object which sent the signal

I would prefer first one.

Answer (score 3):

You can always know who "fired" the event by calling QObject::sender() - http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender . Note that a valid return value is available only when this method is called on a SLOT being called.

Edit:

If you re connecting several signals to a single slot, you should also consider using a signal mapper, which is explained in this QQ:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html